# How to listen message from AWS SQS queue and process it using Sidekiq in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an folder named as dev/ in S3 bucket. I want to get a notification message when any files are added dev/ folder.

I have created a SQS queue named as "myproject-dev" and configured "sqs-dev" queue to dev/ folder in that bucket with event as "PUT".

Configure S3 and receive messages from queue whenever new files are added dev/ folder. I want to below approach is correct. Let me know if anything to be added or removed.

How to receive the messages and pass the messages to Sidekiq Worker and process it? I want to do the same process when new files are added?

How to add a listener in the Rails application which forever to get SQS queue messages?

```
credentials = Aws::Credentials.new(ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_KEY)

@sqs = Aws::SQS::Client.new(
  credentials: credentials,
  region: "us-east-1"
)    

@queue_name = "sqs-dev"


queue_url = @sqs.get_queue_url(queue_name: @queue_name).queue_url
```